# Sort the CSV file on the basis of date

Tags: python, csv, sorting, date

I am making a generic tool which can take up any csv file.I have a csv file which looks something like this. The first row is the column name and the second row is the type of variable.

```
Time,M1,M2,M3,CityName
temp,num,num,num,city
20-May-15,19,20,0,aligarh
03-Sep-14,25,42,7,agra
20-Jan-13,23,35,4,aligarh
20-Feb-15,21,32,3,allahabad
12-May-16,17,27,1,aligarh
25-May-16,16,40,5,aligarh
```

I want to sort the entire file on the basis of date (oldest to newest) in Python but could not find a way out.

Comment: Use `pandas`. It has it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `pandas` should help - first convert first and second csv header to `MultiIndex` by `header=[0,1]` and first column parse to datetimes, last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=[0,1], parse_dates=[0])
df = df.sort_values(('Time','temp'))
#sort by first column
#df = df.sort_values(df.columns[0])
print (df)
        Time  M1  M2  M3   CityName
        temp num num num       city
2 2013-01-20  23  35   4    aligarh
1 2014-09-03  25  42   7       agra
3 2015-02-20  21  32   3  allahabad
0 2015-05-20  19  20   0    aligarh
4 2016-05-12  17  27   1    aligarh
5 2016-05-25  16  40   5    aligarh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('t.csv',skiprows=[1]) 
>>> df.Time = pd.to_datetime((df.Time))
>>> df.sort_values(by='Time')

        Time  M1  M2  M3   CityName
2 2013-01-20  23  35   4    aligarh
1 2014-09-03  25  42   7       agra
3 2015-02-20  21  32   3  allahabad
0 2015-05-20  19  20   0    aligarh
4 2016-05-12  17  27   1    aligarh
5 2016-05-25  16  40   5    aligarh
```